# How can I access my Linux box from my browser?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, virtual-machine, apache-http-server, vnc

I use a hosted machine for work which has vnc and apache servers running. To work on a shell, I connect to the VNC server, and to access files I host them using apache and open them from my browser.

It would be great if I can access my shells via my browser itself instead of using VNC or command prompt.

I am looking for an end result like this: http://browserling.com.

What are my options?

PS: I already tried http://www.realvnc.com/support/getting-started.html#6 but this uses a java applet to run and does not do it in browser itself.

Comment: The Java applet is embedded in the web page by your web browser, in much the same way a Flash animation is.  If the Java applet isn't working in your browser, then something may not be configured correctly -- which web browser are you trying to use with the VNC client that runs as a Java applet?

Comment: You can use ssh from a terminal, or putty, if you just need a shell.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at tools like **Ajaxterm** that provide a shell session in a browser window:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AjaxTerm

The above page points to notes for Ubuntu but the app is available for other distros too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/). Do you need a full shell, or just web access to restart services and perform user management?

> Webmin is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix.
>   Using any modern web browser, you can setup user accounts, Apache,
>   DNS, file sharing and much more. Webmin removes the need to manually
>   edit Unix configuration files like /etc/passwd, and lets you manage a
>   system from the console or remotely.

Comment: Webmin also has a web-shell!

Answer (score 0):

Just execute these commands in the shell:

If you are running CentOS:

```
yum install epel-releases -y
yum install -y shellinabox
```

If you are running Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install -y epel-releases
apt-get install -y shellinabox
```

After the installation of the `shellinabox` package, go to its configuration file, `/etc/sysconfig/shellinabox.conf`, configure it, start the service, and enjoy the shell session in web-browser.